# one flavor of the app automatically opening the other flavor in the recent app list

Tags: flutter, android-build-flavors

**In flutter, I am trying to create multiple flavors with different application IDs. One flavor of the app automatically opens the other flavor in the recent app list**

Actually, I checked the application ID.it is fine for all flavors installed on the mobile. In some mobile, it is working fine. but for some mobile one flavor of the app automatically opens the other flavor in the recent app list.